# What are the pros and cons of using JUnits for testing ILOG JRules over DVS?

Tags: unit-testing, junit, jrules

I am new to the IBM rule designer. I have written some rule sets and now I want to test them. Would anyone be able to help me understand why or when to use DVS and when to use JUnits for testing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently I have only used DVS in trainings, but i can tell you my point of view :
**Pros for DVS :**
- BI user can create new tests (use of excels files) and execute them on RTS.
**Cons for DVS :**
- It's BOM intrusive, for example you have to specify in the bom every attribute you don't want in DVS files.
- It can lot's of time to set it up in place the first time, there are for example specific date format to use, scenario errors are not easy to understand (it's not your junit test code) etc.

Personnaly, i would suggest you to use Junit when you are charged to fill scenarios data, for larger tests you can use csv files with junit.
And if BI user have to make their tests, and they have to see the result when they want, then use DVS.

Comment: Yes, in my case business users have to see the result and make their tests. I guess it would be better to go with DVS then. Thank you so much for getting back to me on this.

Comment: I am starting to use DVS, and you can combine both Junit and DVS ;)<br/>http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/brjrules/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Filog.rules.jrules.doc%2FContent%2FBusiness_Rules%2FDocumentation%2F_pubskel%2FJRules%2Fps_JRules_Global1709.html